# Prove that exist set $B$: $|B|\ge 2014$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $A$ is a set has $2014$ natural numbers. Prove that exist a set $B\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $A\subset B$ and sum square of all elements of $B$ equal area of  all elements of $B$.

I think we can find roots of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}b_k=\Pi _{j=1}^{n}b_j$ with $n\ge 2014$

From my book in Vietnam "(Bài tập số học)
 Problems in Arithmatic", i'm learning elementary - numbertheory by myself.

Comment: What's the area of all elements of $B$?

Comment: is that $\Pi_{j=0}^{m} b_j$ with $b_j\in B$.